# scraping html tags off website in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Is there a way to scrape a website in electron. My goal is to be able to go to a website and scrape the html tags. I am using a windows machine so I launch the app(npm start index.html). My thinking was to create a .js file and use **require** (Url, function(err, resp,html){ }) like you can do in node but this does not work in electron. This code is not able to scrape the page and do a callback. I just want the html only. How can I get this done?
The code in the app.js file that I do a call back on is.

```
function scrape(callback){ 

    var content = [];
    var request = require('request');
    var cheerio = require('cheerio');
    var url = "http://www.amazon.com";



    request(url, function(error, response, html){

       if (error){

          content.push('Error:', error);
       }
       if (response.statusCode !== 200) {

          content.push('Invalid Status Code Returned:', response.statusCode);
     }

      content.push(html);
      var $ = cheerio.load(html);


    $('td').each(function (i, element) {


        var a = $(this).prev();
        var trimmed_a = a.text();

        trimmed_a = trimmed_a.trim();
        var str = trimmed_a.replace(/\s\s+/g,"");
        var newStr = str.trim();

       content.push(newStr);

    });


 })
  callback(content);
}    

module.exports = scrape;
```

The callback works fine but the code is not executed. There is a lot I don't understand so feel free to direct constructively. The goal is to be able to scrape any site with this.

Answer (score -1):

for scraping websites with electron I suggest you to use [NightmareJs](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare).

> npm install nightmare

```
    var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
    var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });

    nightmare
        .goto('https://duckduckgo.com')
        .type('#search_form_input_homepage', 'github nightmare')
        .click('#search_button_homepage')
        .wait('#zero_click_wrapper .c-info__title a')
        .evaluate(function() {
            return document.querySelector('#zero_click_wrapper .c-info__title a').href;
        })
        .end()
        .then(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error('Search failed:', error);
        });
```